# How can I get rid of this weird artifact from a subsurf modifier

Tags: modeling

[image]

Modeling a weapon, and I am getting this weird artifact.  It is only on one corner of the handle and seems to have no relation to the geometry or seams, as far as I can tell. I am trying to keep them all smooth, but one is staying sharp half-way up, not at a marked edge or seam.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to stay sharp you can select the desired edges and press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to add edge creases

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the smooth are what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you send a .blend file? @NickReed

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry, new to  stack exchange

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=NAWO97DJ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/NAWO97DJ/) @INeedHelpWithThisProblemIHave

Comment: @NickReed Your mesh has duplicate vertices in the part where the handle is connected, you can go into X-ray mode with Alt + Z and select the vertices where it's connected to the bazooka

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the actual solution, with the vertices selected press M and merge by distance

Answer (score 2):

Alt + Z to go into X-ray mode for easy selection, select all the vertices from where the handle is connected then press M and merge by distance.

[image]

[image]